# Uncommon checksum representation on the FTP web site

Tags: linux

I'm sorry if i'm asking something basic. I've found list of files with corresponding checkums at ftp://ftp.ensemblgenomes.org/pub/plants/release-39/fasta/helianthus_annuus/dna/CHECKSUMS.

But in my opinion checksum representation is quite uncommon. Before i saw something like `58c1c7a730ba1e90169ab95efdc39e5c` ( got this string as `md5sum` command output on one of the files from the link). How i can convert checksums from link above to regular format?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output looks as it is from `sum` or `cksum`commands.

See [sum wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_(Unix)) and [cksum wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cksum)

You can not use this data to get back a md5sum or shasum.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply! In my case the checksums were got by means of `sum` command.